# Opening a file from the script directory without mentioning entire file path

Tags: python, path

Previously I could open a file from Anaconda's Spyder editor by following command when the file and the script are in the same directory

```
df = pd.read_csv("Results_Space_Type_Comparison.csv")
```

But now, I need to mention the entire path of the csv file even if its in the same directory as the code. Otherwise, it gives this error

```
FileNotFoundError: File b'Results_Space_Type_Comparison.csv' does not exist
```

I haven't made any changes to the path variable or anything else and I don't know what happened. How can I change this back to the way it was previously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify only the name of the file, it depends from which directory the python script is run, wether it is able to find it or not.

You can use the following to get script's dir:

```
import os.path
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

then use that to prepend the path to your filename:

```
os.path.join(dirname, 'Results_Space_Type_Comparison.csv')
```

and it will work in any case.